# Как с помощью прокси-модели сделать исходную модель иерархической в qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractlistmodel

У меня есть исходная модель `source_model = TokenModel(QAbstractListModel)`, которую я использую сразу с несколькими представлениями. Она содержит список токенов `_tokens: list[TokenClass]`. Я также хочу использовать её в QTreeView. Для этого я создаю `TreeProxyModel(QAbstractProxyModel)`, но никак не могу добиться отображения дочерних элементов древовидной структуры. Можно ли преобразовать QAbstractListModel для QTreeView с помощью proxy-модели? Как это сделать?

```
import typing
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QVariant, QAbstractProxyModel

class TokenClass:
    """Класс для хранения информации, связанной с токеном."""
    def __init__(self, token: str, accounts: list[str]):
        self.token: str = token
        self.accounts: list[str] = accounts  # Список счетов.

class TokenModel(QAbstractListModel):
    """Модель токенов."""
    def __init__(self, token_class_list: list[TokenClass]):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QAbstractListModel.
        self._tokens: list[TokenClass] = token_class_list

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество токенов в модели."""
        return len(self._tokens)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            token_class: TokenClass = self._tokens[index.row()]
            return QVariant(token_class.token)
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def getTokenClass(self, row: int) -> TokenClass:
        """Возвращает TokenClass, соответствующий переданному номеру."""
        if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            return self._tokens[row]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Некорректное значение row в getTokenClass() ({0})!'.format(row))

class AccountItem:
    def __init__(self, parent: QModelIndex, account: str):
        self._account: str = account
        self._parent: QModelIndex = parent

    def parent(self) -> QModelIndex:
        """Возвращает родительский индекс."""
        return self._parent

    def data(self) -> str:
        """Возвращает счёт."""
        return self._account

class TreeProxyModel(QAbstractProxyModel):
    """Иерархическая модель токенов."""

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество дочерних строк в текущем элементе."""
        if parent.isValid():  # Если индекс parent действителен, то parent - это токен.
            token: TokenClass = parent.internalPointer()
            return len(token.accounts)
        else:  # Если parent недействителен, то parent - корневой элемент.
            return self.sourceModel().rowCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество столбцов."""
        return 1

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        """Возвращает данные, на которые ссылается index."""
        index_item: TokenClass | AccountItem = index.internalPointer()
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if type(index_item) == TokenClass:
                return index_item.token
            elif type(index_item) == AccountItem:
                return index_item.data()
            else:
                raise TypeError('Недопустимый тип элемента: Тип: {0}, Значение: {1}!'.format(type(index_item), index_item))

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> QModelIndex:
        """Возвращает индекс элемента в модели."""
        if parent.isValid():  # Если индекс parent действителен, то parent - это токен.
            token: TokenClass = parent.internalPointer()
            account: str = token.accounts[row]
            return self.createIndex(row, column, AccountItem(parent, account))
        else:  # Если parent недействителен, то parent - корневой элемент.
            token: TokenClass = self.sourceModel().getTokenClass(row)
            return self.createIndex(row, column, token)

    def parent(self, child: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        """Возвращает родителя элемента."""
        if child.isValid():  # Если индекс child действителен, то child - это корневой элемент или токен.
            data: TokenClass | AccountItem = child.internalPointer()
            if type(data) == TokenClass:
                return QModelIndex()
            elif type(data) == AccountItem:
                return data.parent()
            else:
                raise TypeError('Недопустимый тип элемента: Тип: {0}, Значение: {1}!'.format(type(data), data))
        else:  # Если индекс child недействителен, то child - это счёт.
            return QModelIndex()

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        return self.index(sourceIndex.row(), 0, QModelIndex())

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        parent: QModelIndex = proxyIndex.parent()
        if parent.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()
        else:
            return self.sourceModel().index(proxyIndex.row(), 0, QModelIndex())

class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tokens: list[TokenClass]):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QMainWindow.
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.main_verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView_tokens = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView_tokens)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        source_model: TokenModel = TokenModel(tokens)  # Создаём исходную модель токенов.
        proxy_model: TreeProxyModel = TreeProxyModel()  # Создаём прокси-модель токенов.
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(source_model)  # Подключаем исходную модель к прокси-модели.
        self.treeView_tokens.setModel(proxy_model)  # Подключаем прокси-модель к отображению.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    token1: TokenClass = TokenClass('token1', ['account1', 'account2', 'account3'])
    token2: TokenClass = TokenClass('token2', [])
    token3: TokenClass = TokenClass('token3', ['account1'])
    tokens: list[TokenClass] = [token1, token2, token3]

    window = Form(tokens)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: Окно]

**UPD:**

Мне удалось добиться желаемого отображения данных. Для этого я заменил `QAbstractListModel` на `QAbstractItemModel` и `QAbstractProxyModel` на `QAbstractItemModel`. Замена `QAbstractListModel` на `QAbstractItemModel` позволила мне отобразить значки раскрытия слева от токенов, но само раскрытие завершало программу с ошибкой. Замена `QAbstractProxyModel` на `QAbstractItemModel` убрала эту ошибку. Мне пришлось использовать `QAbstractItemModel` в качестве proxy-модели для `TokenModel`. Это не совсем то, чего я хотел, мне пришлось пойти на компромисс, чтобы получить результат. Для того, чтобы `TreeProxyModel` реагировала на изменения исходных данных, я воспользовался сигналом `dataChanged`.

```
from __future__ import annotations
import typing
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt, QVariant, QAbstractItemModel

class TokenClass:
    """Класс для хранения информации, связанной с токеном."""
    def __init__(self, token: str, accounts: list[str]):
        self.token: str = token
        self.accounts: list[str] = accounts  # Список счетов.

class TokenModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    """Модель токенов."""
    def __init__(self, token_class_list: list[TokenClass]):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QAbstractListModel.
        self._tokens: list[TokenClass] = token_class_list

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество токенов в модели."""
        return len(self._tokens)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return 1

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> QModelIndex:
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            token_class: TokenClass = self._tokens[index.row()]
            return QVariant(token_class.token)
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def getTokens(self) -> list[TokenClass]:
        return self._tokens

    def getTokenClass(self, row: int) -> TokenClass:
        """Возвращает TokenClass, соответствующий переданному номеру."""
        if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            return self._tokens[row]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Некорректное значение row в getTokenClass() ({0})!'.format(row))

class TreeItem:
    def __init__(self, parent: TreeItem | None, data, children: list[TreeItem], row: int):
        self._parent: TreeItem | None = parent
        self.data = data
        self._children: list[TreeItem] = children
        self._row: int = row

    def parent(self) -> TreeItem | None:
        """Возвращает родительский элемент."""
        return self._parent

    def setChildren(self, children: list[TreeItem]):
        self._children = children

    def childrenCount(self) -> int:
        return len(self._children)

    def child(self, row: int) -> TreeItem | None:
        if 0 <= row < self.childrenCount():
            return self._children[row]
        else:
            return None

    def row(self) -> int:
        return self._row

class TreeProxyModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    """Иерархическая модель токенов."""
    def __init__(self, sourceModel: TokenModel):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QAbstractProxyModel.
        self._root_item: TreeItem = TreeItem(None, None, [], 0)
        self._source_model: TokenModel = sourceModel
        self._setTokens()
        self._source_model.dataChanged.connect(self._setTokens)

    def _setTokens(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        token_list: list[TreeItem] = []
        for row, token in enumerate(self._source_model.getTokens()):
            token_item: TreeItem = TreeItem(self._root_item, token.token, [], row)
            token_item.setChildren([TreeItem(token_item, account, [], j) for j, account in enumerate(token.accounts)])
            token_list.append(token_item)
        self._root_item.setChildren(token_list)
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество дочерних строк в текущем элементе."""
        if parent.column() > 0: return 0
        if parent.isValid():  # Если индекс parent действителен, то текущий элемент - это счёт или токен.
            tree_item: TreeItem = parent.internalPointer()
            assert type(tree_item) == TreeItem
        else:  # Если parent недействителен, то parent - корневой элемент.
            tree_item: TreeItem = self._root_item
        return tree_item.childrenCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        """Возвращает количество столбцов."""
        return 1

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        """Возвращает данные, на которые ссылается index."""
        tree_item: TreeItem = index.internalPointer()
        assert type(tree_item) == TreeItem
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return tree_item.data

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> QModelIndex:
        """Возвращает индекс элемента в модели."""
        if parent.isValid():  # Если индекс parent действителен, то parent - это токен.
            token_item: TreeItem = parent.internalPointer()
            assert type(token_item) == TreeItem and token_item.parent() == self._root_item
            account_item: TreeItem | None = token_item.child(row)
            if account_item is None:
                return QModelIndex()
            else:
                return self.createIndex(row, column, account_item)
        else:  # Если parent недействителен, то элемент это - корневой элемент.
            token_item: TreeItem | None = self._root_item.child(row)
            if token_item is None:
                return QModelIndex()
            else:
                return self.createIndex(row, column, token_item)

    def parent(self, child: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:
        """Возвращает родителя элемента."""
        if child.isValid():  # Если индекс child действителен, то parent - это корневой элемент или токен.
            tree_item: TreeItem = child.internalPointer()
            assert type(tree_item) == TreeItem
            parent_item: TreeItem | None = tree_item.parent()
            if tree_item.parent() is None:
                return QModelIndex()
            elif parent_item == self._root_item:
                return QModelIndex()
            else:
                return self.createIndex(parent_item.row(), 0, parent_item)
        else:  # Если индекс child недействителен.
            return QModelIndex()

class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, token_list: list[TokenClass]):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QMainWindow.
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.main_verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView_tokens = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView_tokens)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        source_model: TokenModel = TokenModel(token_list)  # Создаём исходную модель токенов.
        proxy_model: TreeProxyModel = TreeProxyModel(source_model)  # Создаём прокси-модель токенов.
        self.treeView_tokens.setModel(proxy_model)  # Подключаем прокси-модель к отображению.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    token1: TokenClass = TokenClass('token1', ['account1', 'account2', 'account3'])
    token2: TokenClass = TokenClass('token2', [])
    token3: TokenClass = TokenClass('token3', ['account1'])
    tokens: list[TokenClass] = [token1, token2, token3]

    window = Form(tokens)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: окно2]

Если кто-то всё-таки знает, возможно ли превратить исходную модель в иерархическую с помощью настоящей proxy-модели, пожалуйста, напишите, как это сделать.